# Does Rain of Steel damage include any magic weapon enhancements?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Does Rain of Steel damage include any magic weapon enhancements?

i.e. is the damage [1W] or [1W] plus enhancement

> **Effect**: You assume the rain of steel stance. Until the stance ends, any enemy that starts its turn adjacent to you takes 1[W] damage, but only if you’re able to make opportunity attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

Your weapon's enhancement bonus is added to weapon damage rolls. Rain of Steel has the **Weapon** keyword, therefore it is a weapon power. Its damage involves rolling dice, therefore it is a damage roll. Rain of Steel's damage thus receives the enhancement bonus from your weapon.

Comment: Note, however, that it does not gain any bonuses that require an attack to hit, as it does not have an attack roll.